# How do I make a fallback for Facebook Facepile Social Plugin?

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

How would I go about creating a content fallback if the user is not logged into Facebook or does not have any friends who "Liked" my website? The problem I am experiencing is if the above requirements are not met, I get a blank spot on my site where the Facepile plugin would ordinarily show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [FB.getLoginStatus](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) in the JS SDK to see if the person is logged into Facebook and connected to your site.

You can use [FB.api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/) to call [/me/likes](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) to see if the current user liked your site and then conditionally hide/show different elements on the page in JavaScript.